# Clear contents of an input box with jquery when you have multiple on screen

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I have some jQuery code that hides the closest input field in my table row. I want to be able to remove the contents of an input field too, I’ve tried the following:

```
    $(".contact_numbers").on('click', '.clear', function () {
        $(this).closest('input').val(' ');
    });
```

However this hasn’t worked and I’m not sure which other way to approach this, does anyone know how to clear the contents of the closet input field?

My code is in jsFiddle is anyone is willing to help:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal/HCRmQ/7/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Biggest challenge I am facing is finding `.clear` button

Comment: @Satpal it's shown when you click the add button

Comment: @Anton Correct me if I am wrong, OP should have mentioned it

Comment: @Satpal You are correct

Comment: @Satpal sorry but of a rushed question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input is a sibling in the td you must use .closest() to find the parent and then find the inputs like this:

```
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').val(' ');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HCRmQ/8/)

If you want clear the number only then use .siblings()

```
  $(this).siblings('input:text').val('');
```

Comment: thank you was just about to say I should have rephrased my question! but the second solution is best for me! thank you